# In Google Chrome, how do I drag things around on a touchscreen Android device?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, chrome-for-android

Clicking and dragging something from a webpage is easy from a PC. For example, the bar in the screenshot below can be dragged by holding the left mouse button and moving the mouse simultaneously:

[image: Screenshot]

My attempts for doing the same in chrome in android:

- I tried to move it by dragging but the page moves when I do it.
- When I hold over it for some time, a nearby text gets selected and I'm presented with the options to copy, cut , paste etc the selected text.
- Tried to attempt both ways from the stock android browser to see if was a problem in chrome, but failed again.

So, How do I do it in chrome in android?

I'm using chrome 44.0.2403.128 with android 4.4.2

Comment: Can you provide a sample page?

Comment: Sample page: [Ask a question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) or the bar at the bottom of the answer box in this page.

Comment: Does it work in Firefox Mobile?

Comment: Its just a text area (`<textarea>` html tag). It can be expanded using a mobile Chrome Browser too. But its just the way the text area is designed by SO that the resizing icons are interplaced with the draggable textarea. You can do that in the comment box too (which is also a text area) on the bottom right of the box. And its optional since you'll be having a scroll bar added to the textarea if content text inside it reaches the max height.

Comment: @unforgettableid I don't have firefox to test that

Comment: @CoolGuy: Can you install Firefox Mobile for testing purposes? You can get it from the Google Play store or from elsewhere.

Comment: @unforgettableid I just installed it and unfortunately faced the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with just a mouse (or pen) on pages where it is supported. I tested it with a plain USB mouse on my Moto G running Android 4.4.4.

I resized area for post with bottom right striped triangle on "dotaz nebo sdělení" field with mouse. See [this tested page](http://www.ceskatelevize.cz/vse-o-ct/kontakty/).

Or you can pair an ordinary Bluetooth mouse with your device. Probably any modern Android device includes Bluetooth mouse support.

Comment: FYI The example is right here in the comments textarea. It will work here too. ;)

Comment: I tried to resize the bar in the screenshot in my question via a USB mouse connected by one of those 'USB to android cables' and it didn't work. The problem that happens when using the touchscreen happens when using the mouse  too.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

On your slider's position, Double tap and hold on second tap. Then move your finger, you'll notice that you're replicating the left click drag from your pc on a touchscreen.

Comment: "*On your slider's position,*" -- What? Slider? Where? And I tried the rest of the stuff you said in your answer but when moving my finger up, the page zooms out and when I move my finger down the page zooms in. And, Yes. I move my finger when holding on the second tap after double tapping.

Comment: In the red area you marked in your image, double tap on the dotted area

Comment: Doesn't work. The problem mentioned in my previous comment happens.

Comment: Could you provide the website address? I'll try it out and find out if it works

Comment: Click [edit on your answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/117572/edit). You'll find the same bar as in the screenshot. Alternatively, press the "_Answer Your Question_" button below or just go to the [Ask Question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page or edit any answer.

Comment: If I just tap and hold on the control of the text area, I can drag it around, on the condition that you extend it beyond program specified size of the area. Control of text area is the two lines on the right edge of the text area or on the center in the area in your image above.

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking. Could you explain?

Comment: Your suggestion worked elsewhere. But it is tricky to get it right.

Comment: Lol. Have you been trying since August? 

Comment: Worked by accident. Tried again and found it *really* hard to get it right. :-)

Comment: @AnujBatwe, So what's the answer? Can someone explain? I'm using Pixel 2, can't get it to work.